# Curl latin1 encoding

Tags: curl, cmd, riak

I want to post:

```
curl -v -X PUT http://192.168.56.12:10018/riak/vijesti/novadjnada -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"naslov":"Animal","text":"This is croatian word: Šišmiš"}'
```

But when I read that data on Riak on text property there is **"This is croatian word: Ĺ iĹˇmiĹˇ"**

How can I change encoding and where do I need to change it to get valid value?

Comment: Using Riak 2.0 on Ubuntu, I copy/pasted your code line above, changing only the IP, it returned the value exactly as submitted.

Comment: I'm using Riak 1.4.1 on CentOS

Comment: Try specifying the charset in then content type like `-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1"`

Comment: I just changed charset to charset=utf-8 and that solved everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by adding charset to -H option

`curl -v -X PUT http://192.168.56.12:10018/riak/vijesti/novadjnada -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -d '{"naslov":"Animal","text":"This is croatian word: Šišmiš"}`'